# How to make an object only collides with the terrain?

Tags: game-engine, collision

I have a question to the the collision in the Blender Game Engine. I made an character (a simple sphere). This character is on layer 2. A empty object is on layer 1. This empty spawns every 5 seconds a character from layer 2 (Add Object). Is it possible to disable the collision 
of all the characters? They should only collide with the terrain but not with each other.

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple: use collision masks. Download the example file [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VJJFCw6ZHht5NbclATVk2V_2KAL-5-Cx).

The concept is pretty easy:

[image]

- *Collision Group* are the collision 'layers' that the object belongs to. Multiple can be selected.
- *Collision Mask* are the collision 'layers' that the object can collide with. Multiple can be selected.

For example, if *Ball2* belongs to *Collision Group* 2, but can only collide with objects on *Collision Group* 1 (through the use of *Collision Mask*), it will not collide with itself.

[image]